# array data to XML in C

Tags: c, xml, keil, serverxmlhttp

I'm working on LPC 1768 with KEIL IDE . And I want to send a array of the char to client side as a XML file .
but when I get them on the client side , datas changed !
in server side we have 20,000 bytes(char) of data which I have to send client side them.

Here is server code:
At here I fill in buffer with datas for sending

```
    for(fill_loop=0;fill_loop<20000;++fill_loop)
    {
      char_temp = Spi_Flash_read_byte(fill_loop+300);
      /*makes numbers to string*/
      len=sprintf(strReport,"%c",(unsigned char)char_temp);                              
      strcat(str_temp,strReport);
    }
```

And this is a XML file format:

```
t <form>
t <text>
t <id>parameters</id>
c X 1<value>%s</value>
t </text>
t </form>
.
```

How can I fix it?
And where is my wrong?

Comment: Did you think about what happens if one of the read bytes is not printable, for example in the range 0x00 to 0x1F? Or if it is 0x3C? Rethink your choice of the byte coding.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is it . I don't know exactly which byte coding is good for this issue and also i think ,i can use of XML abilities for solving this case. the main problem is in XML

Comment: Reduce your issue to a small experimental program, as professionals do. Try all possible byte values and see what output they generate. Then do your research and find a better way. -- One of many(!) possibilities is to use two characters per byte and use the hexadecimal representation. This doubles the amount to transfer, but it is extremly simple. -- Another approach is to use base64 coding, more appropriate for bigger amounts. -- The choice is yours. Recommendations are off-topic here, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will test your solutions .